# Mongo DB put newer results at top of query with aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm pulling a bunch of results from a collection. I want to display all entries made in the last 30 days first, then sort the rest by number of downloads. Only 10 are loaded at a time, and more are loaded as you scroll.

```
Data.aggregate([
      {'$match': match},
      {"$sort": {downloads : -1, createdAt: -1}},
      {"$skip": page * entriesPerPage},
      {"$limit": entriesPerPage},
      {"$lookup": {
        "from": "examples",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "docId",
        "as": "examples"
      }},
    ]).exec(function(err, docs) {});
```

Right now I'm trying to do it manually by getting all the results and then dividing them into two arrays, but am now realizing that means I'll have to do the $skip part manually too. Also isn't great that I have to load and look through all the results.

Is there a way to do this just as part of the aggregate query?

EDIT: here is a document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ddc3f76853d8286b22bc7b"), 
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T09:39:22.031Z"), 
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-03-31T02:50:31.631Z"), 
"name" : "Dragon", 
"slug" : "dragon", 
"description" : "A dragon is a legendary creature, typically scaled or fire-spewing and with serpentine, reptilian or avian traits, that features in the myths of many cultures around world.", 
"downloads" : 18, 
"type" : "monster", 
"numberOfColors" : 16, "__v" : 1, 
"tags" : [ "monster" ] }
```

There is currently about 100. Again I want to show all where createdAt was within the last 30 days first, then show the rest by number of downloads.

Comment: Could you please post a sample document?

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a temporary helper field for that which you can get by using the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) pipeline stage (or [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) for MongoDB versions < 3.4):

```
var thirtyDaysInMilliSeconds = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

Data.aggregate([
      {"$match": match},
      {'$addFields': { // let's add a field that contains either 0 or 1 depending on whether the "createdAt" value is greater than "today - 30 days"
          "sortHelperField": { $cond: [ { $gt: [ "$createdAt", { $subtract: [ new Date(), thirtyDaysInMilliSeconds ] } ] }, "$createdAt", 0] }
      }},
      {"$sort": {"sortHelperField": -1, downloads: -1}}, // then we can sort by that field, too, and make it the field with the highest priority
      /* all the rest of your stages can stay the way the are */
    ]);
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, I will try it out

Comment: I improved the answer in a way that the first part of the docs (created within last thirty days) should be nicely sorted by date now.

Comment: I ended up using $project since I have 3.2 and it worked well